# javascript addEventListener "message" is sometimes not being received across browser windows

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I am using the `messsage` event to communicate between browser windows. A main window posts to an iframe and the iframe communicates back to the parent. The post always works. php echos back the message using the following:

```
echo "<script>document.write(parent.postMessage(" . json_encode($status) . ", '*'))</script>";
```

Sometimes the message is received and sometimes it isn't. I am sure that the message is being sent since I can log the status message sent after the `echo "<script>...`. What could be causing the issue?

The simplified javascript:

```
// posts login info to an iframe which logs user in 
postToIframe(path, parameters, "post");

// wait for server's response
var foundMessage = false;
var messageFn = function (e) {
    if (typeof e.data.status !== "undefined"){
        _jsonStatus = e.data.status;
        foundMessage = true;
    }
    window.removeEventListener("message", messageFn);
    messageFn = undefined;
    if (!foundMessage){
        _jsonStatus = "Unknown Message: " + v(e.data);
    }
};
window.addEventListener("message", messageFn, false);
var timer = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    var timer2 = new Date().getTime();
    var done = true;
    var message;
    if (_jsonStatus.indexOf('Error') === 0){
        message = _jsonStatus;
        console.log(message);
        done = true;
    } else if (timer2 - timer > 5000){
        message = 'Timeout: Failed to get report data'
        console.log(message);
        if (_this.status){
            _this.status(message, "red");
        }       
        done = true;
        if (typeof messageFn !== undefined){
            window.removeEventListener("message", messageFn);
        }       
    } else if (_jsonStatus.substr(0, 7) == "Success"){
        done = true;
    } else {
        // continue to wait
        done = false;
    }
    if (done == true){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000)
```

Simplified php:

```
if ($userid > 0){
    $status['status'] = "Success. You are logged in.";
} else {
    $status['status'] = 'Error: Login Failed';
}

echo "<script>document.write(parent.postMessage(" . json_encode($status) . ", '*'))</script>";
```

Comment: I love SE. 99% of the time BEFORE posting the question, I figure it out. Most of the rest I figure out just after I post it. In this case the answer was increasing the timeout. I guess my localhost network response needs more than 1/2 second to process.